# Two array element combination in vb

Tags: vba

I want to combine arrays in my program. Take those as an example:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5}
b = {6,7,8,9,10}
```

This should produce an array containing first element of first array with all elements of second array except first element, which is `{1,7,8,9,10}`. This should continue for all possible combinations, producing these output arrays:

```
{1,7,8,9,10} {6,2,8,9,10} {6,7,3,9,10} {6,7,8,4,10} {6,7,8,9,5}...
```

For 2,3,4 elements of first array with second array

```
{1,2,8,9,10} {6,2,3,9,10} {6,7,3,4,10} {6,7,8,4,5} {1,7,8,9,5}...   
{1,7,3,9,10} {6,2,8,4,10} {6,7,3,9,5} {1,7,8,4,10}.....
```

and vice versa for second array.

For the first combination I've tried:

```
For I = 0 To 4 
'first array loop 
    For J = 0 To 4 
    'second array loop 
        If I <> J Then 
           arr(J) = arr2(J) 
        Else 
           arr(J)=arr1(J) 
        End If 
    Next 
Next
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried and explain how it didn't work. See the StackOverflow help center for guidelines how to ask questions on the site.

Comment: I have try below for first combination...

For I = 0 To 4 'first array loop
        For J = 0 To 4 'second array loop  
            If I <> J Then                
                arr(J) = arr2(J)
     Else
  arr(J)=arr1(J)
            End If
        Next
Next

Comment: And please show us the result of this code and explain how it doesn't work - click "edit" under your question to add the information to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: You said you tried something but didn't include the info why did it fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you every combination possible:

```
Function fifth(ParamArray arr() As Variant) As Variant()

Dim temp() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim t As Long
For i = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr)
    If UBound(arr(LBound(arr))) <> UBound(arr(i)) Then
        MsgBox "Arrays not same size"
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
ReDim temp(1 To (UBound(arr) + 1) ^ (UBound(arr(LBound(arr))) + 1), LBound(arr(LBound(arr))) To UBound(arr(LBound(arr)))) As Variant
For i = 1 To (UBound(arr) + 1) ^ (UBound(arr(LBound(arr))) + 1)
    For j = 1 To (UBound(arr(LBound(arr))) + 1)
        t = Int((i Mod ((UBound(arr) + 1) ^ j)) / (((UBound(arr) + 1) ^ j) / (UBound(arr) + 1)))
        temp(i, j - 1) = arr(t)(j - 1)
    Next j
Next i

fifth = temp

End Function
```

You would call thus:

```
Sub ArrCombine()

Dim arr1() As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim rsltarr() As Variant

arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
arr2 = Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

rsltarr = fifth(arr1, arr2)

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(rsltarr, 1), UBound(rsltarr, 2) + 1).Value = rsltarr

End Sub
```

It will output on the active sheet, this:

[image]

This also has the advantage of being dynamic.  You can use more than two arrays.  The only rule is that they need to have the same number of values.

The only other limit is the number of rows on a worksheet.  So (number of arrays) ^ (number of values) cannot exceed 2^20.